# How can i configure font size in gitk?

Tags: linux, git, gitk

Using Linux, how can i configure font and font size in gitk?

Looking through the menus can be quite frustrating as they offer very little configuration possibilities.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can [configure](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk#_files) the font and font size in either:

- `~/.config/git/gitk` or
- `~/.gitk`

Example:

```sh
set mainfont {Monaco 10}
set textfont {Monaco 10}
set uifont {Monaco 10}
```

You can also do it through the tool itself:

1. Open menu `Edit/Preferences`
2. Click `Fonts`
3. Click for example `Main font` to set the properties of the main font

Comment: The file `~/.gitk` is one of three possible locations of the config file. Mine is in `~/.config/git/gitk`. For other locations see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk#_files

Comment: Yes, thie `~/.gitk` is further down the list, so check if `~/.config/git/gitk` exists first. You can see what it opens by running `strace gitk`.